# How to use FOR SYSTEM_TIME clause on a view in a TVF?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, sql-view, temporal-tables

I am trying to use the FOR SYSTEM_TIME clause on a view, which contains system-versioned tables, in a table-valued function.

Per Microsoft's documentation, using the FOR SYSTEM_TIME clause when querying a view should be possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/querying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver16

However, I am getting the following error:

> Temporal FOR SYSTEM_TIME clause can only be used with system-versioned tables. 'dbo.AccountView' is not a system-versioned table.

Function, view, and table definitions:

```
--Account Table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account](
    [Account No] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Global ID]  AS ('A'+CONVERT([nvarchar](10),[Account No])) PERSISTED,
    [User] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Version No] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Version Comment] [varchar](280) NULL,
    [Valid From] [datetime2](2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    [Valid To] [datetime2](2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Account] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Account No] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([Valid From], [Valid To])
) ON [PRIMARY]
WITH
(
SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[hst_Account])
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Account_ValidFrom]  DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()) FOR [Valid From]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Account_ValidTo]  DEFAULT (CONVERT([datetime2](2),'9999-12-31 23:59:59.99')) FOR [Valid To]
GO

--Account_General Table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account_General](
    [Account No] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Main Phone] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [General Email] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Website] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Company] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Valid From] [datetime2](2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    [Valid To] [datetime2](2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Account_General] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Account No] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([Valid From], [Valid To])
) ON [PRIMARY]
WITH
(
SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[hst_Account_General])
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account_General] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Account_General_ValidFrom]  DEFAULT (sysutcdatetime()) FOR [Valid From]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account_General] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Account_General_ValidTo]  DEFAULT (CONVERT([datetime2](2),'9999-12-31 23:59:59.99')) FOR [Valid To]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account_General]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Account_General_AccountNo] FOREIGN KEY([Account No])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Account] ([Account No])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account_General] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Account_General_AccountNo]
GO

--Account_Temp Table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account_Temp](
    [Account No] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Locked By] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Time Locked] [datetime2](2) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Account_Temp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Account No] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account_Temp]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Account_Temp_AccountNo] FOREIGN KEY([Account No])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Account] ([Account No])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Account_Temp] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Account_Temp_AccountNo]
GO

--AccountView
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[AccountView] AS
SELECT a.[Account No]
      ,a.[Global ID]
      ,atemp.[Status]
      ,agen.[Name]
      ,agen.[Main Phone]
      ,agen.[General Email]
      ,agen.[Website]
      ,agen.[Company]
      ,a.[Version No]
      ,atemp.[Locked by]
      ,atemp.[Time Locked]
      ,a.[User] 'Modified By'
      ,CONVERT(datetime2(2), a.[Valid From] AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') 'Time Modified'
      ,ISNULL(ahist.[User], a.[User]) 'Created By'
      ,CONVERT(datetime2(2), ISNULL(ahist.[Valid From], a.[Valid From]) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') 'Time Created'
FROM [dbo].[Account] a
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Account_Temp] atemp
ON a.[Account No] = atemp.[Account No]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Account_General] agen
ON a.[Account No] = agen.[Account No]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ahist.*
          ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ahist.[Account No] ORDER BY ahist.[Valid From])
    FROM [dbo].hst_Account ahist) ahist
ON ahist.[Account No] = a.[Account No] AND ahist.rn = 1
GO

--Table-Valued Function
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAsOfDate_AccountView] (@tblID int, @asOfDate datetime2(2))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
SELECT av.*
FROM [dbo].[AccountView] FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF @asOfDate AS av
WHERE av.[Account No] = @tblID

GO
```

*Edited to add script for view and tables.

Comment: It does have an example of it, @Charlieface : `/* Querying view AS OF */
SELECT * FROM [vw_GetOrgChart]
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF'2021-09-01 T10:00:00.7230011';`

Comment: What SQL Server version are you using? Which table is the versioned one?  From the docs `If the view doesn't reference at least one temporal table, applying temporal querying clauses to it fails with an error.`

Comment: @charlieface Account_Temp is not system-versioned; however, according to the documentation in that same link, "Furthermore, you can combine temporal with non-temporal tables in the same view and AS OF is applied only to temporal ones. If the view doesn't reference at least one temporal table, applying temporal querying clauses to it fails with an error." Account and Account_General are system-versioned.

Comment: According to that link, if you get an error means there's no temporal table in the view. Which table is the temporal one? Post the table definitions so people can try to reproduce the issue

Comment: I wonder if this is an inlining issue. The clause works fine outside of a function, but not inside. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OIRMYvmD) It would have been nice if the OP provided their own [mre] though...

Comment: Sadly this will not work. It *is* permitted to use the `FOR SYSTEM TIME AS OF @variable` construct in a function, but only when it's applied to a base table, not a view. Change your function to use `Account` directly and it will work. Why? Don't ask me, I didn't do it.

Comment: perhaps you can implement whole view in the function itself

Comment: Probably best, in my opinion, for the OP to raise a ticket with Microsoft as "bug".

Comment: @siggemannen Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: if you copypaste whole SELECT a.[Account No]
      ,a.[Global ID]
      ,atemp.[Status]
      ,agen.[Name]
      ,agen.[Main Phone]
      ,agen.[General Email]
      ,agen.[Website]
      ,agen.[Company]
      ,a.[Version No]
      ,atemp.[Locked by]
      ,atemp.[Time Locked]... thing into the function and add the variable conditions you need

Comment: Indeed appears to be a bug to me, it works when not in a TVF https://dbfiddle.uk/UGt6VbJH I think this should be migrated to [dba.se] there are Microsoft employees from the SQL team on there

Comment: putting the specific error code and error state would help to diagnose what specifically is causing your error.

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT It's in the fiddle I linked `Msg 13544 Level 16 State 2 Line 6 Temporal FOR SYSTEM_TIME clause can only be used with system-versioned tables` It's clearly a nonsense, as TVFs can query temporal tables using parameters, and you can use it on views, so why shouldn't this be combined together?

Comment: @charlieface How do I migrate the question to the link you provided? Do I just recreate it at that site?

Comment: No we vote to migrate it. I don't think you can do that, but check if you have the [close] button above

Comment: @ThomA Interestingly it works in a MSTVF https://dbfiddle.uk/xrLQosGb

Comment: I did wonder in an [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76457571/how-to-use-for-system-time-clause-on-a-view-in-a-tvf?noredirect=1#comment134814425_76457571) if it was an inlining issue, @Charlieface . Seems it is. Though I wouldn't suggest switching to an mlTVF for this.

Comment: @thoma Why wouldn't you switch to an mlTVF?

Comment: They are known to perform *very* poorly, @Leah .

Comment: @ThomA I wouldn't recommend either, was just pointing out the difference. I do think this should be migrated.

Comment: if OP is using this function as single select, it shouldn't matter performance-wise even if it's mSTVF. It only becomes a problem if you apply it from some table with many rows

Comment: @Charlieface I asked the engineers to look at this when they can. thx for raising this.

Comment: @ThomA Looks like a view of a view to those tables also doesn't work https://dbfiddle.uk/P4DBIPqg

Comment: @Charlieface A comment on this topic from another forum (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1304100/how-to-use-for-system-time-clause-on-a-view-in-a-t) said that perhaps "there is a restriction with views on views. (An inlined TVF is a parameterised view by another name)." Would this track with what you're seeing while trying to create a view of a view?

Comment: Probably, but it's not documented either way so I'm classing this as a bug

Comment: As general statement, I do try to report each issue to the local engineering teams.  However, if there is a business need for a timely fix, I suggest you open a CSS ticket as the proper route.  Otherwise, it goes in the backlog and the team will work on it whenever it makes sense for them to do so. (not that we like bugs, but there are often competing demands for time for each engineer).  CSS cases will inform formal priority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As have been mentioned in the comments, and after much trial and error by others to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you can't use a variable/parameter in a (i)TVF in the `FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF` clause against a object that isn't itself isn't a temporal object. As such, even if the `VIEW` you are referencing does contain temporal objects you'll get a (some what misleading) error:

> Temporal FOR SYSTEM_TIME clause can only be used with system-versioned tables. 'Sandbox.dbo.PartiallyTemporalView' is not a system-versioned table.

Why it works this way, honestly only someone from Microsoft could likely answer.  You would probably be best opening a ticket (either via your [support plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/sql-server-get-help?view=sql-server-ver15#contact-microsoft-support) or via the [Azure 365 Feedback SQL Community](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/04fe6ee0-3b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0)) with them to raise it as a "bug"; they may give some insight or they might even "fix" the problem (in a future version of SQL Server).

As for a solution, that would be to repeat the definition of the `VIEW` in your `FUNCTION` instead, and use `FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF` against the relevant table(s). That appears to just be `dbo.Account_General` in this case:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAsOfDate_AccountView] (@tblID int,
                                                 @asOfDate datetime2(2))
RETURNS table
AS
    RETURN SELECT a.[Account No],
                  a.[Global ID],
                  atemp.[Status],
                  agen.[Name],
                  agen.[Main Phone],
                  agen.[General Email],
                  agen.[Website],
                  agen.[Company],
                  a.[Version No],
                  atemp.[Locked by],
                  atemp.[Time Locked],
                  a.[User] AS [Modified By],
                  CONVERT(datetime2(2), a.[Valid From] AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') AS [Time Modified],
                  ISNULL(ahist.[User], a.[User]) AS [Created By],
                  CONVERT(datetime2(2), ISNULL(ahist.[Valid From], a.[Valid From])AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') AS [Time Created]
           FROM [dbo].[Account] a
               LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Account_Temp] atemp ON a.[Account No] = atemp.[Account No]
               LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Account_General] FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF @asOfDate agen ON a.[Account No] = agen.[Account No]
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT ahist.*,
                                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ahist.[Account No]
                                                    ORDER BY ahist.[Valid From]) AS rn
                          FROM [dbo].hst_Account ahist) ahist ON ahist.[Account No] = a.[Account No]
                                                             AND ahist.rn = 1;

GO
```

Comment: Added to Azure feedback SQL Community: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/5ab92bba-3d09-ee11-a81c-000d3a0d3715